# Automatically detecting the function directory

Tags: functions

Consider I have a function in `/home/../Mathematica/FuncDir/Function.wl` directory. The function is dependent on some external files, which are in the `FuncDir` directory. To give access to these files, I have used the location of the files inside the function. For example if I am using the file `Hello.txt`, inside the function I simply write

```
hello=Get["/home/../Mathematica/FuncDir/Hello.txt"]
```

Now if I send this function to another machine, the `FuncDir` will be same, but `Function.wl` cannot access the `Hello.txt` file anymore. Can I write a automated directory finder where the function will automatically find its own directory and all the files inside?

Comment: How do you use `Function.wl`? Does simple `Get["Hello.txt"]` not work?